# How to get photos from a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I want to get the photographs from a Facebook page via my Facebook app, where the current subscribed user of my app is an admin of that page. I already have the `manage_pages` permission from the subscribed user in my app.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user pages using-

```
"/me/accounts"
```

Then for any PAGE you can query following using the page access token which you received from the above call-

```
"/PAGE_ID/photos"
```